# lookup new record layout override in lightning

Tags: lookup

is there a way to have a different layout for '+ New [Record]' from Lookup field?

[image: New record from Lookup]

Comment: What do you mean by "different layout"? When you click on that, a form is presented which is defined by the user's assigned page layout.

Comment: when you click New button on the list view of Contacts, its same layout when you click on the + New Contact in the above lookup. I need to have minimal required fields when I click + New Contact, and all fields as defined on layout when clicked New.

Comment: If it's for the same user, that's not possible.

Comment: I found kinda hacked solution. created a record type called 'New' and then changed layout for that and made that record type as default. and once saved, later changed the record type to the actual one.

Comment: And what if you're creating the record from somewhere else? That layout is now the default for anywhere you're creating a new Contact, not just that one location. That doesn't sound like a solution, but if it's what you want..

Comment: yeah doesnt work for all clients. but this particular client he is on field, and this works for him as he wants to have quick create option. and update that later.

Comment: i think you can use a custom component, and filter the fields based on the situation, making the override of the "New" quick action

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do exactly the same on my code but I cant achieve to see the "new Record" option.
Can you please share with us the implementation that you are using on the code to see this option on your input field?

I'm using the next:

```
<lightning:inputField variant="label-stacked" fieldName="FieldWithLookup__c"/>
```

**EDIT**
I know that this is not a solution but my actual reputation doesn't allows me to write comments on the original post.